# What is the difference between these two sentences using infinitive phrase?

Tags: grammar

What differs these two sentences:

> She brought her boy friend to school **in order for** her friends *to meet* **him**.

vs

> She brought her boy friend to school **for** her friends *to meet*.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is confusing because you're changing two variables at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a slight difference in inference between the two.

In both statements, there is an *action* (bringing the boyfriend to school) and a stated *purpose*.

In the first example using "*in order for*", this means that it was the speaker's aim or purpose for her friends to meet her boyfriend.

In the second example that just uses "for", this could imply that the speaker did it *for* her friends, as if it was *they* that wanted to meet him rather than it being the speaker's own purpose that they meet.

Comment: Anyway, how could there be an object 'him' in the first sentence while there isn't in the second.